# ScrollView causing toolbar to extend when soft key shows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

When edittext gains focus(keyboard popups), the toolbar is extended. 
[image: http://imgur.com/Cl6JzWT]

The problem is seen only on pre-lollipop.

Is it the correct way to use scrollview? The inner linear layout height is wrap content.

Here the code of the activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/floatTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/noteContent"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/floatTag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTag"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/tag"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/noteContent"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/floatNote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/noteContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/note"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make both android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" match parent and you forget close </LinearLayout> after scrollView

Comment: @minafawzy thanks. But still same issue exist. Missed closing tag while copying the code.

Comment: try  android:fitsSystemWindows="false"

Comment: @minafawzy this fixes the issue but the toolbar overlaps with status bar.

Comment: remove android:elevation="4dp"

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. Please add it as answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer for your issue to change fitsSystemWidows to false to be like this `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`

Second issue , remove `android:elevation="4dp"`

to be like that

whole your xml file should be like that

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/floatTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/noteContent"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/floatTag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/tag"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/noteContent"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/floatNote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/noteContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/note"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry. There is closing tag for toolbar - mistype. I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this configuration in your main activity:-
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"`

its work for me

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use this inside toolbar

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

If using this code

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

Toolbar overlapping below status bar.